# Solving Congruence Equation

Tags: number-theory

solve: $49x^2+959x\equiv 343 \pmod{1373}$

I've tried like that:

$49x^2+959x\equiv 343 \pmod{1373}$

equal to $7x^2+137x \equiv 49 \pmod{1373} $

equal to $(14x+137)^2\equiv 919\pmod{1373}$

I know $\left(\dfrac{919}{1373}\right)=1$ but I can't find what's $x$, what to do next?

Comment: If your $mod$ is a prime number, you are in a field. So you can do your equation as you always do, by calculating $\delta$ and so on.

Comment: $\left(\dfrac{919}{1373}\right)=-1$  How do you go from $7x^2+137x \equiv 49 \pmod{1373}$ to $(14x+137)^2\equiv 919\pmod{1373}$?

Comment: @sharding4 I multiplied $4$ for 2 sides of $49x^2+959x\equiv 343 \pmod{1373}$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that there are no solutions: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=49x%5E2+%2B+959x+%E2%89%A1+343+(mod+1373)

Comment: That would follow from $\left(\dfrac{919}{1373}\right)=-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments $$\left(\dfrac{919}{1373}\right)=\left(\dfrac{1373}{919}\right)=\left(\dfrac{454}{919}\right)=\left(\dfrac{2}{919}\right)\left(\dfrac{227}{919}\right)=\left(\dfrac{227}{919}\right)=-\left(\dfrac{919}{227}\right)=-\left(\dfrac{11}{227}\right)=\left(\dfrac{227}{11}\right)= \left(\dfrac{7}{11}\right)=-\left(\dfrac{11}{7}\right) =-\left(\dfrac{4}{7}\right)= -1$$

so your equation $(14x+137)^2\equiv 919\pmod{1373}$ has no solutions